# Trying to move apart on-screen panels using CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two panels on a screen with half-screen size each.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left" data-pane="leftpane"></div>
  <div id="right" data-pane="rightpane"></div>
</div> 

<script>
  (function(){
    var left = $('div#left')
    left.on('click', function () {
      console.log('pane clicked');
      left.animate({'width': '+=200'},1000, 'swing', function () {
        console.log($(this).data('pane') + ' ready');
      });
    }); //end onclick
  })();
</script>
</body>
```

and some css

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
}

#left{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100vw / 2 );  
  height:100vh;
  background: #c6c6c6;
}

#right{
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: calc(100vw / 2 );  
  height: 100vh;
  background: #666;
}
```

and when I clicking on a left (for example) block - it grows, as expected, but opposite block dives down, because I don't know how simultaneously and painless reduce its width to preserve original screen size.

it would be nice if panel could "cover over" opposite panel.

any help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `50vw` to be half of `100vw` without using `calc()`

And you can use flex on the parent, define `#left`'s width, then set `#right` to `flex-grow: 1` so it uses the available space... then adjust `#left` as you see fit and `#right` will adapt.

```js
var left = $('div#left')
left.on('click', function() {
  console.log('pane clicked');
  left.animate({
    'width': '+=200'
  }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('pane') + ' ready');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  height:100vh;
}

#left{
  width: 50vw;
  background: #c6c6c6;
}

#right{
  background: #666;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left" data-pane="leftpane"></div>
  <div id="right" data-pane="rightpane"></div>
</div>
```

If you want `#left` to go on top of `#right`, you can use absolute positioning

```js
var left = $('div#left')
left.on('click', function() {
  console.log('pane clicked');
  left.animate({
    'width': '+=200'
  }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('pane') + ' ready');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#left,#right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

#left{
  background: #c6c6c6;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#right{
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left" data-pane="leftpane"></div>
  <div id="right" data-pane="rightpane"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @d2048 you bet :)